# Example from: "Javascript - The Good Parts"

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

What "ugliness" does the following solve? There's something I'm not getting, and I'd appreciate help understanding what it is.

---

For example, by augmenting Function.prototype, we can make a method available to all functions:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
     this.prototype[name] = func;
     return this; 
};
```

By augmenting Function.prototype with a method method, we no longer have to type the name of the prototype property. That bit of ugliness can now be hidden.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, ugliness is subjective, but let's see.

You usually write:

```
function Foo () {}
Foo.prototype.method1 = function ()  { /*...*/ };
Foo.prototype.method2 = function ()  { /*...*/ };
```

You extend the `prototype` object a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_Constructor_Function) with the properties that you want to be inherited to the instances created by the new operator.

For example with `var obj = new Foo();` you are creating an instance of the `Foo` constructor, that object will inherit the all the properties bound to the `Foo.prototype` object and other objects higher in the [prototype chain](http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm).

The Crockford's method does the same, that method is defined in the `Function.prototype` object, all functions inherit from that object, so you can call the method like this:

```
function Foo () {}
Foo.method('method1', function () { /*...*/ });
Foo.method('method2', function () { /*...*/ });
```

It basically just *hides* the `prototype` word  from the code, which Crockford considers  *ugly*...

"JavaScript The Good Parts" is a really good book, but I think is based on the personal perspective that Douglas Crockford has of the language.

I agree with him with a lot of things, but I also disagree with some aspects...

Comment: Using the word "prototype" seems more explicit and obvious when reading the code. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I agree. Crockford is barking up the wrong tree in this case IMO.